# Store Results of Query to A variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I have the following Data:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeLog 
(
     [User] NVARCHAR(6),
     [Event] NVARCHAR(3),
     [Time] DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO TimeLog 
VALUES (N'Mark', N'IN', '2015-04-15 00:31:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'IN', '2015-04-16 20:10:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'IN', '2015-04-21 14:59:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'OUT', '2015-04-22 01:01:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'IN', '2015-04-22 10:46:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'OUT', '2015-04-23 00:58:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'IN', '2015-04-23 14:50:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'OUT', '2015-04-24 01:37:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'OUT', '2015-04-25 01:01:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'OUT', '2015-04-27 00:57:00'),
       (N'Mark', N'IN', '2015-04-17 10:32:00'),
```

I have separated the INs and OUTs to a different column with the query:

```
SELECT 
    [UserName], [IN], [OUT] 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) % 2 AS [PairID],
         *
     FROM  
         [dbo].[AttendanceEvents] 
     WHERE
         UserName = 'Mark') DS
PIVOT
    (MAX([EventTime]) 
        FOR [EventName] IN ([IN], [OUT])
    ) PVT
ORDER BY 
    [PairID];
```

Now I want to store the result of this query to a variable or a table in order to find out the average time from each `Datetime` column, IN and OUT both columns.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide your expected output

Comment: Please note that the query separating the ins and outs to different columns skips values - For example, the 
    `IN` event at `15.04.2015 00:31:00`, `IN` event at `17.04.2015 10:32:00`, `OUT` event at `24.04.2015 01:37:00` are all missing in the results of the pivot query.

Answer (score 1):

You could just define a CTE, and then query that:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [UserName], [IN], [OUT] 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) +
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) % 2 AS [PairID]
        FROM [dbo].[AttendanceEvents]
        WHERE UserName = 'Mark'
        ) DS
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX([EventTime]) FOR [EventName] IN ([IN], [OUT])
        ) PVT
    ) t
)

SELECT AVG([IN]) AS avg_in, AVG([OUT]) AS avg_out
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to do it on the fly:

```
SELECT [UserName]
  ,AVG(DATEDIFF(minute,[OUT],[IN])) AvgMinutes 

FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) % 2 AS [PairID]
      ,*
FROM [dbo].[AttendanceEvents] Where UserName = 'Mark'
) DS
PIVOT
(
MAX([EventTime]) FOR [EventName] IN ([IN], [OUT])
) PVT
GROUP BY [UserName];
```

But if you want to insert it into something, use `insert`.

The something could be a local temp table, global temp table or table variable.

Or you can use the CTE approach previously mentioned.

Here's a sample. You must use appropriate data types. I just used `VARCHAR`

I remove the `order by` because data is never inserted in any order - only when you select it back.

```
DECLARE @MyTableVariable TABLE (
    Username VARCHAR(50),
    In DATETIME,
    Out DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable (UserName, In, Out)
SELECT [UserName]
  ,[IN]
  ,[OUT] 
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName] ORDER BY [EventTime]) % 2 AS [PairID]
      ,*
FROM [dbo].[AttendanceEvents] Where UserName = 'Mark'
) DS
PIVOT
(
MAX([EventTime]) FOR [EventName] IN ([IN], [OUT])
) PVT;
```